# Large function with dynamic k value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table with `name` and `dept` and `salary` column say `A1` to `C10`...

Now I have to provide a name in col `H`, Dept in Col `G` and the Salary column will contain Top value (say if I give 2 in salary column, then it means based on above condition calculate sum of top 2 salary).

I used Large for the condition and `Row(indirect(""))` for salary but `indirect` takes the range `(1:10)` and not the number like 2.

How to achieve this

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you just want sum of top salaries mentioned, say 2 as stated by you?

Comment: Thanks it worked.. Yes i was not able to apply the condition in indirect the way you do it..

Comment: If my answer solved your question kindly mark it accepted.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want top salaries where top number say 2 is entered in a cell then try following formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(LARGE(C2:C11,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&$E$2))))
```

Enter top value in Cell `E2` as shown below:

[image]